# Git eclipse plugin cannot find network drive repository (Windows)

Tags: git, eclipse

I set up a Git repository on a networked drive at home, mapped in my Windows development system to "Y:". When I attempt to commit and push using the eclipse plugin, I get a message saying it cannot find the repository. If I then do a push from the command line just using 'git push' (since the files are committed locally at that point), everything is fine. Is there a difference between the eclipse and command line 'push' so that I need to do something differently? I find the eclipse interface easier, but guess I can use the command line if that's the only one that works correctly in this situation.

My .git/config is as follows:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = y:gitRepositories\\MyProject.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and, from the command line, set your remote URL to:

```
cd /path/local/repo
git remote set-url origin y:/gitRepositories/MyProject.git
```

(I assume the lack of `\\` or `/` between `y:` and `gitRepositories` was a typo)

Comment: The text in the post was actually copied-and-pasted, so no typo. That seems to have done it.

Comment: @arcy OK, the path looked fishy indeed.